# Determine a matrix for the basis/coordinate transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

> Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $R$. Let the following bases of $V$ be given:
>   $$\begin{align} \mathcal{B}&=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)\\ \mathcal{C}&=(v_1,2v_1+v_2-v_4,3v_1+v_3+2v_4,-2v_1+v_2+2v_4) \\ \mathcal{D}&=(2v_2+v_3,2v_1-v_3+v_4,v_1+v_2,3v_1-2v_4)\end{align}$$ Specify the matrices for the following coordinate changes: a) from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{C}$

I'm not really sure if it's right to just take every vector of $\mathcal{B}$ and represent $\mathcal{B}$ by using $\mathcal{C}$:

$\begin{align}
v_1&=1v_1+0v_2+0v_3+0v_4\\
v_2&=2v_1+v_2+0v_3-v_4\\
v_3&=\dots\\
\vdots&
\end{align}$

Therefore, $M^B_C=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & -2\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Try it. In the $\mathcal C$ basis, the coordinates of $2v_1+v_2-v_4$ should be $(0,1,0,0)^T$. Is that what you get when you multiply $(2,1,0,-4)^T$ by this matrix? You’re on the right track, though.

Comment: I would get $(0,1,0,0)$ which would be $v_2$ so it's not the right solution, right?

Comment: Sorry, that should’ve been $(2,1,0,-1)^T$ instead of $(2,1,0,-1)^T$. Did you actually perform the multiplication? When I do, I get $(6,0,0,-3)$, which is most certainly not the expected $(0,1,0,0)^T$.

Comment: And no, $(0,1,0,0)$ when it’s the result of multiplication by $M$, is not $v_2$. Multiplication by $M$ outputs $\mathcal C$-coordinates, not $\mathcal B$-coordinates.

Comment: Eh sry, I missunderstood you. I will get $(12,-3,0,-9)$ which is not the right representation. EDIT: Yeah its $(6,0,0,-3). Thank you for clarification

Comment: I came to a similar solution like Azif00 (did some fixes where I made sign mistakes and now came to the same conclusion), is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the vectors in $\mathcal B$ and put them as a linear combination of the elements of $\mathcal C$. For example, for $v_1$ it's easy to see that 
$$v_1=1v_1+0(2v_1+v_2-v_4)+0(3v_1+v_3+2v_4)+0(-2v_1+v_2+2v_4)$$
So $[v_1]_\mathcal{C}=(1,0,0,0)^t$. For $v_2$ we need to find some scalars $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ such that
$$v_2=a_1v_1+a_2(2v_1+v_2-v_4)+a_3(3v_1+v_3+2v_4)+a_4(-2v_1+v_2+2v_4)$$
i.e.
$$\;v_2=(a_1+2a_2+3a_3-2a_4)v_1+(a_2+a_4)v_2+a_3v_3+(-a_2+2a_3+2a_4)v_4$$
From here, we can conclude that
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
a_1+2a_2+3a_3-2a_4=0 \\
a_2+a_4=1 \\
a_3=0 \\
-a_2+2a_3+2a_4=0
\end{align}
\right.
$$
Solving this, we have $a_1=-2/3$, $a_2=2/3$, $a_3=0$ and $a_4=1/3$. Hence
$$[v_2]_\mathcal{C}=\left(-\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},0,\frac{1}{3}\right)^t$$
and this is what would go in the second column of your matrix. Repeat the same process for $v_3$ and $v_4$ and it's done.
$\textsf{Edit:}$ Just to make sure, I add the rest:
$$[v_3]_\mathcal{C}=\left(-\frac{17}{3},\frac{2}{3},1,-\frac{2}{3}\right)^t$$
$$[v_4]_\mathcal{C}=\left(\frac{4}{3},-\frac{1}{3},0,\frac{1}{3}\right)^t$$
Therefore, the change of basis matrix is the following
$$\textsf{M}_{\mathcal C}^{\mathcal B}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&-\tfrac{2}{3}&-\tfrac{17}{3}&\tfrac{4}{3} \\
0&\tfrac{2}{3}&\tfrac{2}{3}&-\tfrac{1}{3} \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&\tfrac{1}{3}&-\tfrac{2}{3}&\tfrac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}$$
$\textsf{Another way to do so are:}$ Note that the vectors of $\mathcal{C}$ can be written easily as a linear combination of the elements in $\mathcal B$, like that
$$v_1=1v_1+0v_2+0v_3+0v_4$$
$$2v_1+v_2-v_4=2v_1+1v_2+0v_3+(-1)v_4$$
$$3v_1+v_3+2v_4=3v_1+0v_2+1v_3+2v_4$$
$$-2v_1+v_2+2v_4=(-2)v_1+1v_2+0v_3+2v_4$$
Hence
$$\textsf{M}_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal C}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&-2 \\
0&1&0&1 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&-1&2&2
\end{pmatrix}$$
And then
$$\textsf{M}_{\mathcal C}^{\mathcal B}=\big(\textsf{M}_{\mathcal B}^{\mathcal C}\big)^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&-2 \\
0&1&0&1 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&-1&2&2
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&-\tfrac{2}{3}&-\tfrac{17}{3}&\tfrac{4}{3} \\
0&\tfrac{2}{3}&\tfrac{2}{3}&-\tfrac{1}{3} \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&\tfrac{1}{3}&-\tfrac{2}{3}&\tfrac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}$$
It may be easier, maybe not.

Comment: Thank you, now I can compare my solution with yours.

Comment: I add another way to do the computation.

Comment: How would I do this from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$?

Comment: First obtain $\textsf{M}_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{D}}$ with the last method that I exposed and note the following:
$$\textsf{M}_{\mathcal{D}}^{\mathcal{C}}=\big(\textsf{M}_{\mathcal{C}}^{\mathcal{D}}\big)^{-1}=
\big(\textsf{M}_{\mathcal{C}}^{\mathcal{B}} \textsf{M}_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{D}}\big)^{-1}$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint!

Comment: Doesbaddel, your welcome!